# Does c# compiler resolve reference of references during compilation?

Tags: c#, pointers, reference

From C programming language as far as I remember if any pointer is assigned to another pointer, we would use ** prefix for accessing to original value.

How does this work when I pass an object instance to a method as  `ref Myobject myObject` argument. Does c# resolve the  heap address of the object and call `printSomething` in such code below?

```
void testFunction(ref MyObject myObject){
    myObject.printSomething();
}
```

So if this was a recursive function would compiler follow the reference addresses until it finds the object?

I am adding a test scenario below;

```
public class Test
{


    public Test()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        Function(ref str);
        Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
    }

    int referenceCount = 0;

    int Function(ref StringBuilder sBuilder)
    {
        referenceCount++;

        if (referenceCount == 100)
        {
            sBuilder.Append("foo");
            return referenceCount;
        }

        Function(ref sBuilder);
        return referenceCount;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

If I remove if block as expected gives stack over flow exception so for each method call a new reference is reserved in stack.After linking 100 of them to each other I am calling a method on the last one.
Will `sBuilder.Append("foo");` code follow the linked references until it reaches to the object?

Comment: The pointer is the start address of an object.  The structure of the object must be defined the same in c# and c language.  Because c# is managed the object must be moved to un-managed memory by using a Marshal technique.   Using two asterisks either can mean the pointer is an address to an address of an address to an array.  The compile do nothing, you must do all the correct definitions.  The compile just put the start address of the object onto the stack.

Comment: As you´re not re-assigning `myObject` any where in your example, the `ref`-keyword is completely useless. Of course `printSomething` is called for the provided instance. I can´t see any other one. I don´t understand what you´re asking.

Comment: I added a test scenario to clarify things a bit. I hope I made myself  clearer.

Comment: @jdweng There's no point invoke here, it's pure managed c# code

Comment: Isn't  "C programming language" unmanaged.  Read OPs first line.

Comment: @jdweng That describes what the asker remembers from C. The question proceeds to talk entirely about C#. It's important to read the entire question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

Ref in c# isn't pointer in c++. This is different concepts.

> When used in a method's parameter list, the ref keyword indicates that
>   an argument is passed by reference, not by value. The effect of
>   passing by reference is that any change to the argument in the called
>   method is reflected in the calling method. For example, if the caller
>   passes a local variable expression or an array element access
>   expression, and the called method replaces the object to which the ref
>   parameter refers, then the caller’s local variable or the array
>   element now refers to the new object when the method returns.